# In paytm all in one andoid SDK, if paytm app is not installed on the user’s device then not getting the response after the payment successful

Tags: android, paytm

[image]

After payment successful getting 404 errror.

```
        @Override
        public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "Payment Transaction response " + inResponse.toString());
            //not getting response here
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:-

The problem is in Initiate transaction api documentation callbackurl parameter is optional but in sdk integration documentation(Android) callbackurl is mandatory that's why we are facing this issue.

Reference url
https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Payments_Android_Sample_Apps/issues/2

Comment: I have not downvoted your answer just a suggestion that links only answers are discouraged. :)